# SQL. Query Multi Table

Tags: sql

I need to create a query with multiple tables, but I'm not really good at this.

I've got 7 tables.

```
page1_table
page2_table
page3_table
page4_table
page5_table
page6_table
page7_table
```

All tables have row userid as primary and status.

I would need a query that gets all * which is condition;

```
WHERE status = 'No' AND userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of your tables is unclear, but if they all have the same structure, you can union them together in a CTE and apply the filter after the CTE:

```
"select *
from    (
    select * from page1_table union all
    select * from page2_table union all
    select * from page3_table union all
    select * from page4_table union all
    select * from page5_table union all
    select * from page6_table union all
    select * from page7_table
    ) t
where t.status = 'No' AND t.userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with an `INNER JOIN` query

```
"SELECT * 
FROM page1_table a
INNER JOIN page2_table b
ON a.userid = b.userid
INNER JOIN page3_table c
ON b.userid = c.userid
INNER JOIN page4_table d
ON c.userid = d.userid
INNER JOIN page5_table e
ON d.userid = e.userid
INNER JOIN page6_table f
ON e.userid = f.userid
INNER JOIN page7_table g
ON f.userid = g.userid
WHERE a.status = 'No' 
AND a.userid = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Forgot that i needed union.